# Updating a JSON with AJAX Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

It's been hours I'm searching for a, I guess, simple answer.
I have this JSON file

```
 "billets": [
{
  "idBillet": "103AHT",
  "fk_user": "Robert",
  "validite": "Pas validé",
  "titre": "Muse",
  "date": "10/04/2016",
  "heure": "21:00",
  "lieu": "Centre Bell, Montréal",
  "description": "Venez voir le groupe Muse au centre Bell au beau milieu du mois de juin! Bières fraîches recommandées pour se rafraîchir !",
  "imgURL": "http://grgrezrezrefzfz.com/AlbumMuse.png",
  "qrURL": "http://grgrezrezrefzfz.com/QRCodeMuse.png"
}]
```

I can acess it through a local API on http://localhost:3000/billets

My question is simple :
How can I change the value of

```
"validite" : "Pas validé"
```

to

```
"validite" : "Validé
```

with Ajax Query js ? I tried POST and PUT but can't achieve what I want...

My actual code looks like :

```
function validBillet() {
 var idBillet = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("idBillet").value);

var URL = "http://localhost:3000/billets?idBillet="+idBillet;

        var dataObject = { 'validite': "Validé", 'validite': "Pas validé" };

        $.ajax({
            url: URL,
            type: 'POST',    
            data: JSON.stringify(dataObject),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function(result) {
                (data[0].validite="Validé");
                alert("success?");


            }
        });

}
```

Do you have an idea ?
Thank you,
Romain

Comment: That depends entirely on what software is running on the server.

Comment: Actually I am using "Json Server" to fake API. It works with basic HTTP GET PUT UPDATE POST

Comment: max means this question is unanswerable without server code. The javascript sends a request to the server to change the value, then it's up to the server's code to read the request and change the file.

Comment: Sorry, I just started Javascript... If it can helps, the full code is on git at https://github.com/typicode/json-server with its doc

Answer (score 0):

The variable data you use in success callback is not yet defined.

Simply call : `dataObject.validate = "Validé";`

Comment: Thank you, I tried that, but doesn't work :

$.ajax({
    type: 'PUT', // Use POST with X-HTTP-Method-Override or a straight PUT if appropriate.
    dataType: 'json', // Set datatype - affects Accept header
    url: "http://localhost:3000/billets?idBillet="+idBillet,
    data: '{"validite": "Validé"}', // Some data e.g. Valid JSON as a string
    dataObject.validate = "Validé"
});
}

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible for Javascript to change or write to a file on the server and that's for a security reasons.

So you need to use a server side language to achieve that like PHP as follow:

```
var dataObject = { 'key' : "validite", 'value': "Pas validé", 'replace': "Validé" };

$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "server.php",
  data: { dataObject }
})
```

Then create a PHP file: server.php with this code inside it:

```
<?php
$jsonString = file_get_contents('jsonFile.json');
$data = json_decode($jsonString);

foreach($data->billets as $item){
    if($item->$_REQUEST["dataObject"]["key"] == $_REQUEST["dataObject"]["value"]){
        $item->$_REQUEST["dataObject"]["key"] = $_REQUEST["dataObject"]["replace"];
    }
}
$newJsonString = json_encode($data , JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);

file_put_contents('jsonFile.json', $newJsonString);
?>
```

Comment: Thank you really much for your answer, it works perfectly ;) Have a nice day!